# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска названий фотографий

Tags: регулярные-выражения, изображения

Пожалуйста, помогите составить Regex, чтобы находило:

- цифры
- "-300x300" (данное вхождение опционально)
- расширение файла ".jpg"

Примеры названий фото:

- 4870071000256.jpg
- 4870071000256-300x300.jpg

Comment: `\b\d+\.jpg` что нибудь такое

Comment: Огромное спасибо, а можно еще как-нибудь, чтобы еще могло быть наличие строки "-300x300" ? Типо такого: 4870055002689-300x300.jpg

Comment: `\b\d+-300x300\.jpg`

Comment: @Houckz я думаю вам лучше отредактировать вопрос,  приведя пример того что у вас есть и то что вы хотите получить в итоге, подумав какие входные данные возможны и что должно быть динамическим, а что статическим. Это поможет не только вам, но и тем кто будет помогать с решением.

Comment: @Houckz `\b\d+(?:-300x300)?\.jpg` необязательное наличие -300x300 указывается так

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи на PHP:

```
<?php
$str = "4870071000256-300x300.jpg";
if (preg_match("/\d+(-300x300)?\.jpg/i", $str)) {
    echo "Вхождение найдено.";
} else {
    echo "Вхождение не найдено.";
}
?>
```